# Shows error while starts the app ( Abi Incompitable )

Tags: android, opencv

Iam new to android ndk , i have created basic app with android ndk and i have already created all mk files ( android.mk and application.mk )  how to solve the abi error

```
enter code here   LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

#opencv
OPENCVROOT:= C:\OpenCV-OpenCV 3.2-android-sdk
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
include ${OPENCVROOT}/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_example_working_new.cpp

LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog
LOCAL_MODULE := MyLibs

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

my Application.mk file

```
enter code here    APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-16
```

Answer (score 1):

the simple way is to make all APP_Abi  for different platforms and emulators edit this in your application.mk file.

```
enter code here
```

APP_ABI :=all

Comment: am going to try this